# See App Timeline View

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-timeline

From the app details, (Apps -> xxx -> App Details) there is a list of links (relaterede links) in the left side of the page.

When I go to the "See App Timeline View" link, it's shows my personal timeline, why?